# Remove adjacent duplicates from a list prolog

Tags: list, prolog, duplicates

I'm new to Prolog and I need to remove duplicates from a list like shown in the example below.

```
?- remove([a,a,b,c,a,a,b,c,b,a,a],X).
X = [a,b,c,a,b,c,b,a]
```

Comment: what happens with `[a,a,a]` ?

Comment: What should be the answer for `remove([X1,X2],[Y1,Y2])`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to remove *adjacents* duplicates. Just copy the elements skipping the first of adjacents. I'll let you to complete the code...

```
remove([X,X|Rest], [X|Rest1]) :-
   !,   % this commit avoid the logical alternative you'll code below
   .... % recurse to get Rest1 from Rest
remove([X|Rest], [X|Rest1]) :-
   % recurse to get Rest1 from Rest
% remember the base case !!
```

**edit** as false pointed out, such naive remove/2 is buggy. I've corrected adding a remove/3 predicate, that does the copy accounting for a witness, i.e. with an element lookahead.

```
remove([X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
  remove(X, Xs, Ys).
remove(X, [X|Xs], Ys) :-
  !,  % discard the duplicate
  ... % recurse to get Ys from Xs, with same witness
remove(_, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
  ... % the cut above ensure that here we must change witness when recursing
% as always, remember the base case !!
```

Comment: `remove([a,a,a,a],[a,a])` would succeed in your case, intended?

Comment: @false: no, it's a bug! Sorry I was confident in and didn't tested. I'll edit the answer with your catch...